# Integral of ration polynomial; $\operatorname{artanh}$ vs $\ln$

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to integrate the following function analytically (wrt $x$), but with some software (preferably maple):
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}
$$

I look at wikis integration table which states:
[image]

For my problem: $(4ac-b^2)<0$, meaning the $\ln()$ integral should work. And indeed, it does work (I integrated it by hand). However, comparing the results to the $\operatorname{artanh}()$ integral did not work for my problem. I did this because some math book (Merziger, Mühlbach et al. 2013) said that the $\ln()$ integral is equal to the $\operatorname{artanh}()$ as long as $(4ac-b^2)<0$ (which, as I said, is true for my problem).

The thing is, I'm trying to integrate the functions using Maple or WolframAlpha. However both these programs will always result in the $\operatorname{artanh}$ integral, which yields the wrong results for my problem. This makes sense, as in wiki, the condition next to the $\operatorname{artanh}()$ integral is not met in my problem. I discovered the wiki integration table only recently, but unfortunately I'm too dumb to compute $\operatorname{arcoth}()$, as it's not implemented in python. (I'm sure I'd find some way to compute it though, if necessary).

Can someone help me find a solution? E.g. is it possible to tell Maple to use the $ln()$ instead of $\operatorname{artanh}()$? (Or some other software?)

Comment: Mathematica has [TrigToExp](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html) and [ExpToTrig](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpToTrig.html). WA usually lets you get away with wrapping your input with either of these, like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=trigtoexp+arccoth%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29). Also, $\coth^{-1}(x)=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac1x\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following identity to convert from $\tanh^{-1}x$ to $\log x$ :
$$\tanh^{-1}x=\frac{1}{2}\log \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) $$